# How does garbage collection work with Node.js HTTP(S) requests?

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory, garbage-collection

I am repeatedly calling a function that executes an HTTPS request, similar to the following:

```
const https = require('https');
foo()
{
  const request = https.request('https://stackoverflow.com', { method: 'GET' }, (response) =>
  {
    let output = '';
    response.on('data', (data) =>
    {
      output += data;
    });
    response.on('end', () =>
    {
      console.log(output);
    });
  });
  request.on('error', (error) =>
  {
    console.log(error);
  });
  request.end();
}
```

Does this code cause memory to leak? My understanding is that the request and response objects will be eligible for garbage collection once they are "inaccessible", but I am uncertain as to precisely what this requires. I would assume that the `const` reference to the request object is no obstruction as it presumably falls out of scope once `foo` terminates, but what about the event listeners, which appear to survive `foo`? It seems that they should persist the request and response objects to allow for the HTTPS request to be processed even after `foo` terminates, presumably resulting in a leak. Or, perhaps the event listeners continue to function even if the request and response objects are released? But in this case, wouldn't the event listeners themselves still persist, again resulting in a leak?